# SystemState backup on SBS 2011 Std. - How many hours would you allow it to run?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2011, system-state

I'm doing a migration of SBS 2011 Std to Server 2019 following server-essentials.com documents.  This is for a 10 user domain.  Exchange is on the SBS box but mail is being handled by o365.  This is certainly not doing anything 'fancy'  It's the lone server in the domain. No line of business apps on the server.

It feels like I am on step 2 of 1000 steps : )  each of the few tasks I've tried / done has evolved into searching on the web to get past errors.

I am now trying to do a systemstate backup.  The instructions say to run this command

wbadmin start systemstatebackup –backuptarget:g:

(is backuptarget case sensitive? Because it would error and show syntax example of ....-backupTarget).  Changing that t to T seems to  get it working.

There's an external USB 2.0 2TB hard drive (formatted as NTFS) on drive G.

That was 3? hours ago.  See the pic of the PS window.  It' hasn't changed / added another line for 2 hours?

The hard drive has about 42.7GB of files on the drive now.  Oh, 10 minutes after typing that, it's now at 45.3GB.  so it IS still running / not hung?!

I've been using shadowProtect all these years to backup the server.

And SentinelOne is on the machine.

Googling, I found this page:

https://support.axcient.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010658228-Backup-for-Files-The-system-state-backup-process-failed-with-the-following-exit-code-3

and running those 3 commands of diskshadow
a) none have a windows\ entry
b) I saw the shadowprotect and sentinelone VSS in there.

I haven't done a system state backup a long time ago if ever.

Any idea how much longer this should take? Does that string of results look right? It warns it might take several MINUTES, not hours : ) THANKS!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGJAZ.jpg)

Comment: I mentioned shadowprotect and sentinelone having vss entries / drivers...

Would you think they would interfere with system state backup?  It's 4 1/2 hours now.

Comment: Sorry, you still have your other backup product installed? Yes, get rid of it. It takes minutes to do a systemstate backup of a 60 GB drive for a domain controller to a local disk for me. If it's not network latency, it might be the other stuff.